# Password Resetting view displays the django framework template

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-allauth

Password Resetting view displays the Django framework template instead of my HTML template. Even after adding template name in my urls.py, I still don't get any improvement

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserRegisterView, AddProductView, CategoryView, UserEditView, PasswordsChangeView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
from .views import *

app_name = 'members'

urlpatterns = [
    # path('signup/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    # path('account/', UserEditView.as_view(), name='edit_account'),
    path('account/', views.edit, name='edit_account'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
    # path('password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='registration/change_password.html')),
    path('password/', PasswordsChangeView.as_view(template_name='registration/change_password.html'), name='password'),
    path('add_product/', AddProductView.as_view(), name='add_product'),
    path('add_category/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset.html'),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Tho, It only works for this path`('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),`
Thanks for your help,:)

Comment: The `password_reset` is also used in admin site password reset path, so change it to `reset_password` or `change_password`.

Comment: but other urls does not display the template